# How to print a function which has been passed in as a parameter?

Tags: python

Please bear with me! I'm used to programming in C and I just started learning python.

I have a main function and a stub function as follows:

```
def main_function(string):
    print(string)

def stub_function():
    return 'some random string'
```

I want to pass in my stub_function into my main_function and ideally be able to print out 'some random string'.

```
main_function(stub_function)
```

But I keep getting:

```
<function stub_function at 0x7f21f07e0d08>
```

I've tried searching but I can't seem to find anything that I can understand. What is going on here and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You passed a function to `main_function`, so obviously it prints a function, and not a string. If you want to obtain the string, you have to *call* the function.

Answer (score 1):

You must call the function for it to return the value.

```
main_function(stub_function())
```